# Outlook 2016 Birthday Calendar Bug?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar, debug, microsoft-office-2016

I was adding a birthday to a contact in Outlook 2016 (Pro. Plus Edition), and noticed that it created an event in my primary ("Austin's Calendar") calendar, and a "Birthdays" calendar. I expected the latter, but noticed that it's been doing the former for a while now... I was able to perform a search on that calendar and found it had happened with other contacts I've added birthdays to.

- Event Title Format for Calendar "Birthdays": [name]'s Birthday
- Event Title Format for Calendar "Austin's Calendar": [name] birthday

Is this a bug, or am I missing a setting somewhere? This just seems like odd functionality, and I find it somewhat annoying as well, as I would get two notifications on the day of the birthday on a mobile device, if both calendars are synced. However, what would be the purpose of a "Birthdays" calendar then?